# How to append the two lines string in php json response

Tags: php, json

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "name": "Chicken Shawarma",
        "price": "510.00",
        "nutrients": "A
        B "
    }]
}
```

this is the my json response , In My app i setup a two line record for "nutrients". Ex :

```
A
B
```

this vale saved in database without any issue (My SQL), now i want display the "nutrients" data as a two line record. but its displaying below error

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

if you have any idea please share with me.

this is the my server side code

```
        if ($itemInfo->num_rows() == 1) {
        $row = $itemInfo->row_array();       
        $json_arr = $_GET['callback'] . '(' .
                "{'name' : '" . $row['name'] . "',"
                . "'nutrients' : '" . $row['nutrients'] . "',"
                . "'img' : '" . $row['img'] . "'}" . ')';
    } else {
        $json_arr = json_encode(array('status' => 'N'));
    }

    echo $json_arr;
```

this is the my client side code

```
    $http.jsonp(full_url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.item = data ;
    });
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code.

Comment: Try putting a backslash right after `A` : `A\`

Comment: If you are making this JSON directly in your PHP code use "nutrients": "A\nB" instead.

Comment: @jeroen added relevant code , please can you help me

Comment: @MateiMihai this values taking for textarea input box  & this box fill by client so we can't put "\n". if i wrong please correct me

Comment: @Ostrovski this values taking for textarea input box & this box fill by client so we can't put "\n". if i wrong please correct me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is making a JSON response by concatenating strings. In such case you miss required encodings/escaping and so on. So, first of all you should create an associative array and then do `$json_arr = $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($your_json_like_array).')';` exactly like in the `else` clause.

Resulting code should look like this:

```
$json_arr = array(
    'name' => $row['name'], 
     ..., 
    'nutrients' => $row['nutrients']
);
$json_arr = $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($json_arr).')';
```

Comment: Thanks you answer is correct , but i have another issue , this is a ionic app, now json response coming as a two record

Comment: @ChamaraMaduranga does it relate to this question or it's another problem?

Comment: ya it related to the question , what happen was now data coming to the js level , but it not displaying correctly , i think first  i have to study that issue , i will check that issue & let you now , thanks very much for your support.